# CocoaPods - Explicitly updating a dependency conflict issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am facing a scenario where I need AFNetworking 3.0. But signalR has a dependency on AFNetworking 2.0, So it causes a conflict

```
 target “MyTestApp” do
  pod 'SignalR-ObjC', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
 end
```

Now when I try an explicitly update (pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'), then I got error

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

AFNetworking (~> 3.0) required by Podfile
AFNetworking (~> 2.0) required by SignalR-ObjC/Core (2.0.2)
```

How should I resolve this conflict?

Another way, if I try to update AFNetworking (included by SignalR)

```
target “MyTestApp” do
 pod 'SignalR-ObjC', '~> 2.0'
end
```

then

```
[!] The [AFNetworking] Pod is not installed and cannot be updated
```

So, how can we update this explicitly?

Comment: SignalR-ObjC in its PodSpec seems to accept only AFNetworking 2.0 (https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/blob/feature-dev/SignalR-ObjC.podspec). So you can't have AFNetworking 3.0 at the same time for your project. Either it will be updated to have dependency on AFNetworking 3.0 or you are stacked into AFNetworking 2.0 if you want to use SignalR-ObjC

Comment: That's correct, but I want an explicit update and then I will update the SignalR for AFNetworking 3.0.

Comment: I'd suggest that you fork SignalR, update its code (to accept AFNetworking 3.0, and of course, updating also the pod spec ), and then include that version. With CocoaPods you can use either local repo or distant, private or public (if you fork on a GitHub, or just have your special version accepting AFNetworking 3.0 locally on your Mac).

Comment: You'd be best to follow the issue about this on the SignalR-ObjC repo: https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/issues/233

Comment: I fork SignalR, but I there is an issue with  [pods.xcodeproj file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235606/signalr-pods-xcodeproj-missing). I tried to resolve it, but I am still stuck here.